# JAVA mouselistener gives incorrrect x and y coordinates

Tags: java, mouselistener

Here I have two classes, one including main function. I want to draw a rectangle which moves automatically. But the starting point of rectangle is not the same as the point i clicked with mouse. I could not figure out this problem. Can you help me?

This is the first class including main function

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BuyuyenSuDamlalari extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    BuyuyenSuDamlalari bsd1 = new BuyuyenSuDamlalari();
    frame.setContentPane(bsd1);
    BuyuyenSuDamlalariClickListener bscl = new BuyuyenSuDamlalariClickListener(bsd1);
    bsd1.addMouseListener(bscl);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

int x;
int y;
int radius;
int click;

public BuyuyenSuDamlalari() {
    super();
    setFocusable(true);
    Timer zaman = new Timer(40, this);  // bir saniyede 25 resim oluyor
    zaman.start();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (click>0) {
        g.drawRect(x, y, radius, radius);
    }
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    radius++;
    repaint();
}
public void setClick(int click) {
    this.click = click;
}

}
```

This is the second class wihich includes motionListener

```
import java.awt.event.*;
public class BuyuyenSuDamlalariClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

private BuyuyenSuDamlalari bsd = new BuyuyenSuDamlalari();
private int x;
private int y;
public BuyuyenSuDamlalariClickListener(BuyuyenSuDamlalari bsd) {
    super();
    this.bsd = bsd;
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    if (e.getClickCount()>0) {
        bsd.setX(e.getX()-25);
        bsd.setY(e.getY()-25);
    }
    bsd.setClick(1);

}
}
```